# Hot to retrieve the Sparepoint Guid by given ItemId

Tags: node.js, sharepoint, pnp-js

I am wondering whether there is way to retrieve the Guid (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx) from an given ItemId (eg. ItemID=1969 as in query params in https://xyz.sharepoint.com/path/to/documents/image.jpg?ItemID=1969&ItemVersion=5.0) with pnpjs under nodejs.
The docs do not describe how to do that but there might be a way to use a "back-door" to achieve this.
I would like to do something similar like:

```
sp.web.
  .getById(1969)
  .get()
  .then((file) => {
     doSomethingWith(file.UniqueId); //UniqueId is supposed to be the guid (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)
  })
...
```

Any suggestions are welcome.
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the below way to retrieve the file uniqur id

```
  sp.web
    .lists
    .getByTitle("Documents")
    .items
    .getById(80)
    .file
    .get()
    .then((file)=>{
      console.log(file.UniqueId);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

**I think you should use "GUID" instead of "UniqueId"**
see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest) and find this part of the documentation.

**Retrieve specific list item**
The following example shows how to retrieve a specific list item.

HTTP GET

```
https://{site_url}/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Test')/items({item_id})
Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
```

The following XML shows an example of the list item properties that are returned when you request the XML content type.

XML

```
<content type="application/xml">
  <m:properties>
    <d:FileSystemObjectType m:type="Edm.Int32">0</d:FileSystemObjectType>
    <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:Id>
    <d:ID m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:ID>
    <d:ContentTypeId>0x010049564F321A0F0543BA8C6303316C8C0F</d:ContentTypeId>
    <d:Title>an item</d:Title>
    <d:Modified m:type="Edm.DateTime">2012-07-24T22:47:26Z</d:Modified>
    <d:Created m:type="Edm.DateTime">2012-07-24T22:47:26Z</d:Created>
    <d:AuthorId m:type="Edm.Int32">11</d:AuthorId>
    <d:EditorId m:type="Edm.Int32">11</d:EditorId>
    <d:OData__UIVersionString>1.0</d:OData__UIVersionString>
    <d:Attachments m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:Attachments>
    <d:GUID m:type="Edm.Guid">eb6850c5-9a30-4636-b282-234eda8b1057</d:GUID>
  </m:properties>
</content>
```

**as you see returned value contains GUID tag**

Comment: THX Eshan Mandegar. Your feedback covers the raw REST method not the pnpjs. Besids this your example operates on lists. I am trying to fetch data for files. According the pnpjs docs files (https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/v1/sp/docs/files/) and lists (https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/lists/) are treated different. Unfotunately the files section does not cover my specific case. Am I on a completely wrong path here?